# Topology and Categories for the Visually Impaired

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, category-theory, education

Are there any books (and/or other reference material) for teaching topology and/or category theory for the visually impaired?

For example, a teacher may have experience with tactile learning tools enough to demonstrate simplicial (and even CW) complexes. From there it's not too hard to talk about Betti numbers, and  the Seven Bridges of Konigsberg.  But it might start to get a little more challenging for the embarassingly visually-dependent teacher (myself) to prove mulitplicativity of Euler characteristic.

Also, are there references available for students?  Do there exist any topology and/or category theory works that are translated into Nemeth?

Comment: I do not know, but read [this article](http://www.ams.org/notices/200210/comm-morin.pdf) to see if you can find some useful tips. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmanuel_Giroux is a famous blind topologist. Maybe by googling articles about him you can find out how did he learn topology.